# Neural Network Architecture for Graph Inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have an undirected graph with edges of equal distance with 7 features per node. I want to train a Neural Network with this graph as an input and output a scalar. What network architecture do I need for my network to analyse the graph locally (for example, a node and it's neighbours) and to generalise, much like Convolutional Neural Networks operate on grid data. I have heard of Graph Neural Networks however I don't know if this is what i'm looking for. Will it be able to analyse my graph much like a CNN does with an image, sharing the generalisation benefits that convolution kernels bring?

I want to implement the solution in TensorFlow, ideally with Keras.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The performance will most likely depend on the exact output that you're hoping to get. From your description a 2D-CNN should be good enough and easier to implement with Keras than a GNN.

However, there are some advantages to retaining the graph structure from your data. I think this is too much to present here, but you can find a proper explanation on "Spatio-Temporal Analysis and Prediction of Cellular Traffic in Metropolis" by Wang et al.

This paper also has the benefit of describing data processing to input into the network.

If you don't want to use basic Keras models to assemble your own GNN you may also want to take a look at [Spektral](https://github.com/danielegrattarola/spektral), which is a python library for graph deep learning.

Without any other constraints I would firstly use a CNN, because it will be faster to implement with almost ready to use models from Keras.

Comment: How can I use a CNN if I have a graph structure? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: At the end of the day you will still have to extract features from your nodes and organize them into a structure fitted for the input to one of the deep learning models, like a tensor or a multidimensional array. How you arrange your data depends mostly on your particular scenario.

There is a section on Spatio-Temporal Modelling in the article I provided that goes into detail for their particular case. This may help you gain some insight on one possible approach.